Birationality Class of Elliptic Pencil
Following basic construction causes confusion. We consider the linear system of plane cubics $\vert O(3)_{\Bbb P^2} \vert $ on complex projective plane $\Bbb P^2$ (especially every general member is smooth, and every smooth member admits a rational point, so is an ellipctic curve. (NB: I assumed that we work over $\Bbb C$, but think most of this can be transfered to any alg closed base field of char $\neq 2,3$).
Pick $2$ general (so smooth) members $F_1,F_2 \subset \Bbb P^2$.
These define only a rational dominant pencil
$$f_{F_1,F_2}: \Bbb P^2 \dashrightarrow\Bbb P^1$$
due to base locus where it is not defined. Blowing it up in this undeterminancy locus - this consists of exactly $9$ points $V_+(F_1) \cap V_+(F_2)$ we get a dominant regular map
$$Blf_{F_1,F_2}: S \to \Bbb P^1$$
whose general fibre is still a cubic, so an elliptic curve, so we have an elliptic pencil.
Question: I'm stucking in conflict on how to determine which birationality type $S$ must have. On one hand $S$ is obtained by blowup ups at points, so still birational to $\Bbb P^2$. On the other hand the function field $K(S)$ of $S$ coinsides with function field of generic fibre of $Blf_{F_1,F_2}$ - which as $Blf_{F_1,F_2}$ is an elliptic pencil is an elliptic curve $E$ over $K(\Bbb P^1)$, but I doubt that such a curve is rational in sense that $K(E) \cong K(\Bbb P^2)$. As $K(S)=K(E)$ this is paradox.
Anybody see my stupid reasoning error?
Motivation: Methods for construction of relative minimal models of elliptic pencils.

@CraniumClamp: here some ideas why I think so: $S$ is smth surface, let set $C:= \Bbb P^1$ for proj line and (all objects are smth, so no non reduced issues), let $\eta_C, \eta_S, \eta_E \in E:= f^{-1}(\eta_C$ be generic points of $S, C$ and generic fibre $E$ resp. Function field $K(X)$ of integral scheme = stalk $O_{X, \eta_X}$ at it's generic point $\eta_X$. So can work locally and our $f: S \to C$ looks locally affine as ring map $R:=k[T]_s \to A$. Locally the generic fibre is given as $A \otimes_R K(R)$ and as localization of rings is transitive, passing

to generic fibres (=inverting all non zero elements stepwise, first from $R$, then from $A$) gives $K(A) = K(A \otimes_R K(R))$, so generic stalk of $S$ coincides with generic stalk of the generic fibre. (Note, this works only because $R \to K(R)$ is flat). So function fields of $S$ and $E$ coinsides. Your point with "dimension" shift has to do with that $K(E)$ has transcend dimension $1$ over $K(C)$!, $K(S)$ trans dim $2$ over base field $k$! Is the argument ok?

Yes, you are right about the function fields (because the generic fiber is a curve over k(T) which I overlooked, and hence I deleted my comment earlier). However, the surface is indeed rational.

@CraniumClamp: Yes, that's exactly the problem, as blowup hot change the birat type, $S$ should be rational of dim $2$, so $K(S) \cong k(X,Y)$ purely trnscendtal over base field $k$, but on the other hand have we have tower of extensions $K(E)/K(T)/k$ with $E/K(T)$ elliptic, so not rational with resp $K(T)$. Can we still see that $K(E)$ is purely(!) transcendental over $k$? (The purely is important; the right transcend degree=2 surely fits)

Yes, I understood what you are wishing for as an answer: to prove that the function field K(E) (which is the same as K(S)) is isomorphic to k(x,y) purely algebraically. We know it is, from geometric considerations as S is a blowup of P^2.

@CraniumClamp: Ok, aproaching this from that direction that is of course "tautological" that $K(E)$ is rational due to construction of $S$. I argree, then the way the question is formulated is misleading; should next day add the background. The motivation was this and the linked discussion with abx in MO; the point was that there was a certain elliptic pencil $S \to \Bbb P^1$ initially given and abx suggested that it's minimal model - which must be neccessarily birat to this $S$ - is given by the

construction with these blowup I described above. So the question is if the initial $S$ is also rational in order that the blowup construction from above is indeed the minimal model of initial $S$. So, ok, next days I should add more background to turn the question into a more consistent one

I believe this is the kind of answer that you want. We may, and can work on an affine chart.
Let $ f_1 = f_1(x,y) $ and $ f_2 = f_2(x,y) $ be the two equations defining the two elliptic curves. The pencil of elliptic curves parametrized by $ t $ is then given by the equation $ f_1 + tf_2 $, i.e. $ \operatorname{Spec} R $ where $ R $ is $ k[x,y,t]/(f_1 + tf_2) $
Clearly $ R $ is a domain as the polynomial is linear in $ t $ hence, irreducible. The same statement shows that any polynomial $ g(x,y) $ cannot be in the ideal $ (f_1 + tf_2) $ hence that $ k[x,y] $ is a subring of $ R $. So the fraction field $ K(R) $ of $ R $ contains $ k(x,y) $.
But in $ K(R) $ we have $ \frac{1}{t} = \frac{-f_2}{f_1} $ hence $ K(R) = k(x,y) $ in fact.

just as nb although presumably clear: to deduce that $f_1+tf_2$ is irreducible (=prime, as our ring is UFD), we need to assume that $f_1,f_2$ not share a prime factor, but then the pencil would have base points where it would de not welldefined (even the base locus would have codim $1$; but we excluded it, as the pencil is regular). Also, always nice to know that then we could use a version of Gauss lemma to prove irreducibility of this polynom instead of in $k[t,x,y]$ in more familar $k(x,y)[t]$, assuming the "coefficients" of $t$ not share common factor

Another interesting question rasing from this would be, let assume we have given an elliptic curve $E/k(t)$ over $1$-rational field $k(t)$ (where char of $k \neq 2,3$ in order to have Weierstrass form), but assume we don't have this additional information about existence of the pencil etc,  just this elliptic curve over $k(t)$. Is it possible to decide when $E$ is rational over $k$ in general? Equivalently, that there exist a transcendetal base of two elt's $x,y \in K(E)$ generating $K(E)$ as $k$-algebra and $trdeg_k(K(E))=2$.
